# C# JsonConvert - List of Lists with Multiple Types

Tags: c#, json, list, serialization

So I'm trying to parse a JSON request that looks a bit like this:

```
{
"source_code":"MOODY",
"code":"DAAAYLD",
"name":"Aaa Corporate Bond Yield",
"data":[
    [
        "2015-08-11",
        3.96
    ],
    [
        "2015-08-10",
        4.06
    ],
    [
        "2015-08-07",
        3.96
    ]
]
}
```

There's a few more items I've left out but they're not important. Now, I'm using

```
var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResponseObj>(GetRawData(code));
```

to make a JsonResponseObj which looks like:

```
public class JsonResponseObj
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("code")]
        public string code { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("source_code")]
        public string source_code { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public List<List<string>> data { get; set; }
    }
```

This works fine for getting the name, codes etc. if I omit the "data" property, however because the data itself is a list of lists (or list of two-tuples if you want to look at it that way) I'm not quite sure how the correct way of fetching this is. I've tried a few things which all seem to break the parser, including the most obvious one to me of:

```
[JsonProperty("data")]
public List<Tuple<string, float>> data { get; set; }
```

However that just gives an error of:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'System.Tuple`2[System.String,System.Single]' because the type
>   requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize
>   correctly.

But the actual type isn't a JSON object, as it has no Key/Value pairs, just 2 values for each type of "string, float".

Any clues on how this would be best parsed to get the data?

Comment: Are you the one creating the JSON? If you do, making those inner arrays objects instead, your problems would be gone.

Comment: Your best bet would be to write a custom Converter then. If you don't have to send that data back, then you can just leave the writer with an `NotImplementedException`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so I've discovered dynamic types which do away with having a seperate static object for the JSON which didn't work with nested list strings.

Basically I solved it with one line of code:

```
dynamic jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(rawJsonStr);
```

Which means I can then call on the top-level values directly, and use a JArray to iterate through the "data" list as below:

```
string name = jsonData.name;
string data_code = jsonData.code;
string source_code = jsonData.source_code;
JArray data = jsonData.data;
foreach (var point in data)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(point[0] + " | " + point[1]);    
}
```

Comment: If it solved your problem, you can accept your own answer.

Comment: Thanks cvreb, but apparently the system will only let you accept your own answer 2 days after posting the question (not sure if that goes down with higher rep). =)

Comment: I was not aware of that! So we wait ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem exists because of *data* it's not List>, because each entry contains string and double element so i've a quick solution for this issue just implement your class as the following.

public class JsonResponseObj
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

```
    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public string code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("source_code")]
    public string source_code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public List<Dictionary<string,double>> data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Nope, that gives me an error:

Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[System.String,System.Double]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object ({"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to type to force it deserialize from JSON array.

Comment: Okay replace Dictionary<string,double> with Dictionary<string,object>

Comment: Without altering deserialization rules, this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "source_code": "MOODY",
  "code": "DAAAYLD",
  "name": "Aaa Corporate Bond Yield",
  "data": [
    {
      "2015-08-11": 3.96
    },
    {
      "2015-08-11": 3.96
    },
    {
      "2015-08-11": 3.96
    }
  ]
}
```

I config syntax `.json`, like this, you will use `List<Dictonary<string,float>` data like u want

```
public class Root
{
    public string source_code { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string,float>> data { get; set; }
}
```